# Add an object to another object contained in one of the first's class attributes, Java

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I have a class called Club that contains an ArrayList of persons, which are objects. Each Person has a club attribute of type Club. To add persons to the club, I have made a method, addMember, that takes a Person object and adds it to the desired ArrayList.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
public class Club {
...
    public void addMember(Person person) {
        person.setClub(**This instance of club**);
        this.memberList.add(person);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: `person.setClub(this);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to reference this instance. It's not only a way to access properties and methods, but also a reference.

```
person.setClub(this);
```